# Why my syncronized axios method is falling into error in react javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, axios

I have a component class calling my service method:

```
const requestLogin = (username, password) => {
    let response = authService.login(username, password);
    console.log("test1");
    console.log(response);
    console.log("test2");
}
```

And here is the service method that making request to backend:

```
export function login(username, password) {
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/auth/login",
        data: {username: username, password: password}
    }).then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error('Network Error'); //error from axios
        }
        return res.json();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message) //to display the error to your user just use the useState to define your error
    })
}
```

After that execution, actually backend is responding correctly and I see jwtToken from backend in **Network** tab, but in console I only see:
[image]

Where am I doing wrong ? I just want to check if the jwtToken is coming successfully and response code is 200 then I want to navigate to another page but why my debug console outputs showing this?

Comment: You don't return anything from the `login` method: your return statement is for the *callback to .then*, not for the outer method. You will need to return the axios call and `await` it where you want to use it. There are plenty of resources for this around the web [including the official axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Api calls are asynchronous by nature. If you want to wait for the response use:

```
let response = await authService.login(username, password);
```

Other than that, are you sure your response has ok attribute in it? because res.ok could be undefined and !res.ok clause will be true. SuccessfullCallback is a function that will run when response code is 200, there shouldn't be a case where you need to check for invalid response in successCallback function.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't actually return the axios call, the return of the `login` method is `undefined` so `await`ing doesn't actually help.

Answer (score 1):

The response of `axios` does not contain a property called `ok`. The response schema can be found [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema).

The other issue with your code is that your `login` function does not return anything currently, which is why that just prints `undefined`.

Depending on what you want to do, you can either return the call of the `axios` request `return axios({...})` which will give you a `Promise` back that you can handle with `then/catch`, or you can define your `login` function as an `async` function and use `await` and return the response that way.

Either way you need to handle the returning `Promise` from your `login` function.